# Is there a Python function that can clone objects?

Tags: python

I know that one can clone a list when adding a square brackets with a colon in between, an example of what I mean here:

```
list_clone = original_list[:]
```

However, when it comes to types of data that are not subscriptable(in my case objects), are there any alternative functions that can clone these objects? Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Have you seen [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) ?